# date in Flask URL

Tags: python, flask

Whether there is a correct way to pass date (for example, '2015-07-28') as url parameter in flask, like for integer:

```
@app.route("/product/<int:product_id>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

I need something like:

```
@app.route("/news/<date:selected_date>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not out-of-the-box, but you can register your own [custom converter](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/routing/#custom-converters):

```
from datetime import datetime
from werkzeug.routing import BaseConverter, ValidationError


class DateConverter(BaseConverter):
    """Extracts a ISO8601 date from the path and validates it."""

    regex = r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'

    def to_python(self, value):
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
        except ValueError:
            raise ValidationError()
 
    def to_url(self, value):
        return value.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


app.url_map.converters['date'] = DateConverter
```

Using a custom converter has two advantages:

- You can now trivially build the URL with `url_for()`; just pass in a `date` or `datetime` object for that parameter:

  ```
    url_for('news', selected_date=date.today())
  ```
- Malformed dates result in a 404 for the URL; e.g. `/news/2015-02-29` is not a valid date (there is no February 29th this year), so the route won't match and Flask returns a NotFound response instead.

Comment: i'm still trying to understand how dates work when passed as part of a object in POST methods, but need special handling like this when passed as part of GET path..

Comment: @SonicSoul: the parsing of data in the *path* is independent of the request method. You can use this is a POST request just the same as in a GET. The request *body* you send in a POST is not part of the URL path, so parsing that is something completely different.

Answer (score 2):

A simple example that works for me:

```
@app.route('/news/<selected_date>', methods=['GET'])
def my_view(selected_date):

    selected_date = datetime.strptime(selected_date, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
```

Answer (score -2):

with works in this case because there is no slash in your date format. Otherwise it will be considered part of the URL.